# Why does a Decimal number get rounded automatically and.. also conditionally?

Tags: apex, decimal

Okay so I noticed something lately.

Let's say we have a number that is calculated and passed along to a Number field.
On a page layout if we view the field, we might see it rounded.

```
1.000,00
```

If we click the edit button and then we click on the text box we might see a slight different representation, a more precise one

```
999,999999999999999999999989
```

If I query for this I get a number like this

```
999999999999999999999999989.00
```

Which is confusing to say the least. Because when precision matters how do I know exactly when I should round it? This looks like a different number, too. And how do I even round this on the decimals, it already is.

Now here's another thing I noticed.
If I serialize the query result (EDIT: and then deserialize) I will actually get this number. (EDIT: In other examples I might see the scientific notation of the *not* precise version of the number)

```
1000
```

Thank god. But I don't get why this happens.
Is that the solution?

Cause as you might have noticed if I do nothing boy do I love the script thrown exceptions that are on the way